# PHP Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

This is driving me nuts!

This is what I want to achieve:

Part 1: pseudo-element must start with `[a-zA-Z0-9]` then it can or not have ONE `[._-]` or ONE `space`

Part 2: it must finish with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

The part 1 can repeat forever, but it must finish with part 2.

It tried like a million ways of doing it and it never works. With the code that I have below if I put "Test_*test" (with TWO "*") it works when it shouldn't. Please help

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="pseudo"/><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Valider"/>
    </form>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['pseudo']))
        {
            $pseudo = $_POST['pseudo'];

            if(preg_match('/([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}[._-]{0,1})+[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}$/',$pseudo))
            {
                echo "Ok";
            }else
            {
                echo "Error";
            }
        }       
    ?>

</body>
```

Comment: Do you mean: "then it can have ONE `[._-]` or ONE space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must escape the `-` and `.` like so `[\._\-]` because it is a special symbol, and then try adding the `^` sign in front of the regular expression

Comment: No, `.` is not a special symbol inside a character class and `-` is only special if it is between characters, not at the end or beginning.

Comment: Thanks that works. I don't quiet understand why it needs "^" when I say that it should have at least one letter and THEN zero or one symbole

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
/^([[:alnum:]]+[._ -]?)+[[:alnum:]]+$/
```

`alnum` is an alias for letters and digits.

Comment: Don't you need to switch `-` and `<space>` or does it work because space is before the hypen in the ASCII table?

Comment: If it is in `[]` brackets, it can be in any position.

Comment: But then wouldn't you use the `-` to indicate a range, not the character `-`?

Comment: `-` must be at the beginning, at the end or escaped if it should be taken literally. `[._ -]`, `[-._ ]` or `[._\- ]` will do.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[._ -]?)+[a-zA-Z0-9]$/
```

The start and end with alnum are obvious here, but the internal part basically enforces that any of `[._-]` will be surrounded by "*NOT* `[._-]`"

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[._-]{0,1})+[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

Comment: You can use `?` instead of `{0,1}` :)

Comment: Great thanks, it's been a while since I did this kind of stuff